# Replicating an autoinstall

Tags: server, updates, storage, user-data, autoinstall

My scenario is as follows.

I've deployed several servers, and each has generated the /var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data.
Of course, things have changed on the devices, i.e., network config and storage config.

Now, I'd like to create a new version of the autoinstall-user-data that matches the server's current config. For the network, it seems relatively straightforward to extract the current netplan config. However, is there any way to do a similar operation for the storage? i.e., extracting it in a suitable format to replace the old storage config found in the autoinstall-user-data file?

Clarification;
After the initial installation, the storage config was this;

```
node:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1822
loop1    7:1    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop2    7:2    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
loop3    7:3    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop4    7:4    0  40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20290
sda      8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:17   0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:18   0   446G  0 part /
```

After some tinkering, post-install, the storage config looks like this;

```
node:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0    7:0    0  63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1822
loop1    7:1    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
loop2    7:2    0  49.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
loop3    7:3    0  63.5M  1 loop /snap/core20/2015
loop4    7:4    0  40.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/20290
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0   1.8T  0 part /data
sdb      8:16   0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─sdb2   8:18   0   446G  0 part /
```

Any tool/method that allows me to update the storage config in autouser-install, to match the new storage layout?

BR/Patrik

Comment: Have you read this? [Automated Server Installation](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to do an *autoinstall* installation where you're able to specifically define your storage config. This is easily done by configuring your storage layout in a `user-data` file that *Subiquity* and *curtin* will reference during installation.

As you mentioned in your question, a standard server installation generates a file called `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data`. So as a start, you can simply copy the storage config section from this file and add it to a custom `user-data` file that you'll use as your *autoinstall* file for future installations.

For example, on a standard server installation for Ubuntu 22.04.3, here is the storage config section that is generated and shown in `/var/log/installer/autoinstall-user-data`.

```
  storage:
    config:
    - ptable: gpt
      serial: VBOX_HARDDISK_VB33ff5bd3-8d67f93f
      path: /dev/sda
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: true
      type: disk
      id: disk-sda
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1048576
      flag: bios_grub
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 1048576
      path: /dev/sda1
      type: partition
      id: partition-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 2147483648
      wipe: superblock
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 2097152
      path: /dev/sda2
      type: partition
      id: partition-1
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 24692916224
      wipe: superblock
      number: 3
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 2149580800
      path: /dev/sda3
      type: partition
      id: partition-2
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices:
      - partition-2
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - name: ubuntu-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 12343836672B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-0
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-1
    - path: /
      device: format-1
      type: mount
      id: mount-1
    - path: /boot
      device: format-0
      type: mount
      id: mount-0
```

This generated a storage layout on `/dev/sda` with LVM as follows:

```
$ lsblk
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                       7:0    0  63.4M  1 loop /snap/core20/1974
loop1                       7:1    0  53.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/19457
loop2                       7:2    0 111.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24322
sda                         8:0    0    25G  0 disk 
├─sda1                      8:1    0     1M  0 part 
├─sda2                      8:2    0     2G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0    23G  0 part 
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0  11.5G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

To use this standard storage configuration in an *autoinstall* installation, create a `user-data` file as follows. Take note, however, that I removed a few unnecessary keys such as `serial` and `path` that fall under various `device` top-level keys. Additionally, the `autoinstall` and `identity` keys are required, as is the first commented line, `#cloud-config`. This config defines a default user of `ubuntu` and password of `ubuntu`, which is hashed. A different password can be created with `mkpasswd --method=SHA-512 --rounds=4096`. Change accordingly.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  version: 1
  identity:
    hostname: ubuntu-server
    password: $6$5lpwCLsKLEzMkSJc$keOAhA6aO/5RocGThmhVA7LSNuW911Rx5HHXFEa75oGK20cEdAAgn14H5f5nGeq6QgcSyLPrWcg1.JvjXbhrN/
    realname: Ubuntu User
    username: ubuntu
  storage:
    config:
    - ptable: gpt
      wipe: superblock-recursive
      preserve: false
      name: ''
      grub_device: true
      type: disk
      id: disk-sda
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 1048576
      flag: bios_grub
      number: 1
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 1048576
      type: partition
      id: partition-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 2147483648
      wipe: superblock
      number: 2
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 2097152
      type: partition
      id: partition-1
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: partition-1
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-0
    - device: disk-sda
      size: 24692916224
      wipe: superblock
      number: 3
      preserve: false
      grub_device: false
      offset: 2149580800
      type: partition
      id: partition-2
    - name: ubuntu-vg
      devices:
      - partition-2
      preserve: false
      type: lvm_volgroup
      id: lvm_volgroup-0
    - name: ubuntu-lv
      volgroup: lvm_volgroup-0
      size: 12343836672B
      wipe: superblock
      preserve: false
      path: /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
      type: lvm_partition
      id: lvm_partition-0
    - fstype: ext4
      volume: lvm_partition-0
      preserve: false
      type: format
      id: format-1
    - path: /
      device: format-1
      type: mount
      id: mount-1
    - path: /boot
      device: format-0
      type: mount
      id: mount-0
```

For more information on customizing the storage configuration, read the docs at [Automated Server installer config file reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toL9t.png) as well as the [curtin documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTqqa.png).

---

Documentation at [Automated Server install quickstart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13w6u.png) indicates that you can utilize the `user-data` file in one of several ways for an installation. You can read the documentation to study yourself.

- By providing *autoinstall* data over the network
- By using another volume to provide *autoinstall* data

However, you can also add the custom `user-data` file to an ISO by unpacking the ISO file, adding the `user-data` file as well as a blank `meta-data` file, modifying grub, and then repacking the ISO. An easy way to do this is using *Cubic*, which I'll outline below.

---

## Add custom `user-data` file to an ISO using Cubic

### Run Cubic

1. Select your working directory
   [image]
2. Select your ISO. I'm using *ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso*
   [image]
3. Click *Next* to continue
   [image]
4. On the next page, select the *Preseed* tab and upload your custom `user-data` file and a blank `meta-data` file to the *preseed* directory
   [image]
5. Select the *Boot* tab and edit the `grub.cfg` file as follows:
   [image]

   You are specifically changing the 10th line to the following. Take note of the directory name where we placed the `user-data` and `meta-data` files. It is */cdrom/preseed/*, which is what was already created in Cubic.

   ```
    linux   /casper/vmlinuz  autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/preseed/ ---
   ```

   Here is the entire `grub.cfg` file:

   ```
    set timeout=30

    loadfont unicode

    set menu_color_normal=white/black
    set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

    menuentry "Try or Install Ubuntu Server" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  autoinstall ds=nocloud\;s=/cdrom/preseed/ ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
    }
    menuentry "Ubuntu Server with the HWE kernel" {
        set gfxpayload=keep
        linux   /casper/vmlinuz  ---
        initrd  /casper/initrd.gz
    }
    grub_platform
    if [ "$grub_platform" = "efi" ]; then
    menuentry 'Boot from next volume' {
        exit 1
    }
    menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' {
        fwsetup
    }
    else
    menuentry 'Test memory' {
        linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
    }
    fi
   ```
6. Click *Next* to come to the following page. Click *Generate* to create your custom ISO.
   [image]
7. When complete, you'll see this page
   [image]

---

After this, your custom ISO can be used for an *autoinstall* Ubuntu 2.04.3 Server installation.

Comment: I've added some clarifications about my case.

Comment: @PatrikArlos You have? Where? Your question has not been updated with any new info.

Comment: :facepalm: forgot to press save, closed browser. Updated now.